# Does Open Office need to be installed to be used by a deployed application?

Tags: c#, winforms, openoffice.org

I am thinking of using Open Office from my winforms application to produce printouts of data.  I would like to reference the API and programmatically manipulate documents from my client PCs. To clarify, I don't want to host a window with Write inside it so users can edit documents from within my application.  I just want to programmatically stick a load of data into a document and call print on it, so the only thing a user will see is the print options dialogue box.

I can't install Open Office on my client PCs. Is it possible to xcopy install the Open office dlls (hopefully just a subset) along with my application binaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [AODL](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL)

It is a part of the ODF Toolkit.

/Erling Damsgaard
DNS-IT ApS